# FiddlerCore uploading larger file

Tags: video, proxy, large-files, uploading, fiddlercore

I'm having an issue when I try uploading larger file(s) when FiddlerCore proxy is turned on, is there a reason for this, seems like some buffering issue. Anyone could explain/help ?

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the "issue"?
2. How large are we talking, exactly?
3. What does the code for your FiddlerCore application look like?
4. Are you compiling your application for 32bit or 64 bit?

Comment: The issue I noticed when I was uploading a video to youtube. it was about 230MB. Uploading stopped without any response. when I closed my proxy app, and tried again, it was ok. The proxy app was compiled for any cpu. the code is pretty simple, basically it's a blocker for certain sites, in request event I track to see if URL is blocked (in blacklist), and if yes, in response event I'll just place specific message HTML as an actual response instead of original web response. that app acts like a parental advisory app.